# casting 8-bit pointer to long

Tags: c, pointers, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to use a 3rd party c library in my c++ project, which I develop using Visual Studio on Windows 64-bit. 
Both 32bit and 64bit compiled successfully; however, I found an issue in the external library when running in 64bit, as it does the following:

```
double* foo(){
     double* b; long a; long i;
     /*
       ... do some stuff to assign values to b, a, i ...
     */
     return ( (long)b + a + i );
}
```

The problem is (on windows at least) that double* is represented by 4 bytes in x86 architectures and 8 bytes in x64 , so casting of `b` in the return statement is screwed.

My question is, is there a way I can "extract" the 4-bytes address of pointer `b` from its 8-bit representation, so as to keep the expression `(b+a)` meaningful?

Thanks

Comment: Please learn the difference between bit and byte, it's essential for effective communication of ideas. Pointers are four or eight bytes, not bits.

Comment: I might miss something obvious, but would simple removing (long) from the return line not solve the problem?

Comment: The code in question makes zero sense. It is unclear what it is designed to do, so it's hard to tell what would be an appropriate fix. If it's your code, my advice would be to avoid any and all casts.

Comment: @n.m. I think the casting is to make the addition behave as if a and i are quantities in bytes, not doubles. The issue would be because perhaps `long` on Windows 64 is only 32 bits so the pointer would get truncated.

Comment: If this is third party library code, I would throw it away or at the *very* least give it a recompile with warning level at the maximum and all warnings treated as errors, then hand-analyze each warning and think how to eliminate it.

Comment: I would suggest just rewriting as much of the code in this function as you can such that it operates in some sensible way. Start by thinking of the last line as `return b + ((a + i) / sizeof(double));` and figure out how to get the `sizeof(double)` out of there by arranging the values of `a` and `i` to be in terms of doubles.

Comment: I would guess that what you are looking for is `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @MTilsted: I thought so, too, and I tried it. The result was that the return values were pointing to memory locations that had nothing to do with the intended objective, and hence caused different issues down the line.

Comment: @n.m. : apologies for the bits/bytes mix-up. It was honestly a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the cast is to avoid doing pointer arithmetric on multiples of `sizeof(double)`.

You can do the same with `char *` pointers, avoiding the size issue completely. I also added cast back to original pointer type which code was missing.

```
return (double *)( (char *)b + a + i );
```

**Note:** You should be aware that you can easily create unaligned pointer, which can lead to *undefined behaviour* if dereferenced. This was also problem with your original code.

Be careful; your code looks very questionable, and it may have other potential mines.

Comment: jackpot! changing (long) to (char*) did the trick. Now the x64 version behaves exactly as its x86 counterpart.

Comment: @gcaglion Glad it worked. But like I said, that pointer arithmetric makes me a bit nervous. Out of curiosity, can you reveal what the library is?

Comment: I never use pointer arithmetic myself, but, as I wrote, I decided to use an existing 3rd party external library to save some time, and I actually did. By the way, the external code is from http://svmlight.joachims.org/ (specifically, function kernel_cache_clean_and_malloc() in svm_learn.c

Comment: @gcaglion It was last updated back in 2008, when dinosaurs still roamed the Earth. The site looks like it's straight from 1998. But I have downloaded the library out of curiosity, and couldn't find such code in it. There is a lot of spurious and dubious casts in it for sure.

Comment: @n.m. It's probably the code in the line 3711. Funny thing is, it seems that integer conversion was pointless: There is `sizeof(CFLOAT)` which is used to multiply the pointer increment manually.

Comment: @user694733 ah yes missed it somehow.